# How to edit website live and insert CSS and JS except developers mode

Tags: css, editor, live

I have a website that is not responsive. My task is to make it responsive. I didn't have source files, the client requires a CSS and js files that he will add to the website. I am doing it by editing live via chrome developer

I want to know that is there any extension or software which I can use to insert code live into the website.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Nope!

But you can style it in (chrome developer mode mobile view) and paste its media query `css` in separate file and then send it to them so that he add that style in style sheet at the end. Added screenshot for reference.

https://www.screencast.com/t/vWhqsxVsq